# How to setup web2py enviroment for unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, web2py

I have the following directory structure:

```
web2py/applications/myapp
web2py/applications/myapp/controllers/account.py
web2py/applications/myapp/models/db.py
web2py/applications/myapp/tests/runner.py
web2py/applications/myapp/tests/test_account.py
```

In `account.py`, there is a function accessing `models/db.py`, for instance

```
def calcExpense():
    rows = db(db.expense.id >0).select()
    expense = blah and blah..
    return expense
```

In `test_account.py`, I would like to test `calcExpense`:

```
class TestAccount(unittest.TestCase):
    def testCalcExpense(self):
        self.assertTrue()
suite = unittest.TestSuite()
suite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(TestAccount))
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

If I run under `web2py` directory with `python web2py.py -S myapp -M -R applications/myapp/tests/test_account.py`, everything is fine thanks web2py setting all required environment.

But I don't want to run unittest one way for web2py (under `web2py` directory), and another way for the all other python projects (under `tests`).

In particular, I want to run all tests through the test runner, under `tests` by:

```
`python -m unittest -v runner`
```

How can I setup the enviroment in `runner.py`, so that `test_account.py` can import `account.py`, `account.py` have access to both `db.py` and tables defined in `db.py`?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a web2py environment using the `env` function in the `gluon.shell` module. For some ideas on how to proceed, check out [web2py.test](https://github.com/viniciusban/web2py.test), in particular, [here](https://github.com/viniciusban/web2py.test/blob/master/tests/conftest.py#L85).

You might also want to look at an older project, [web2py Test Runner](https://pythonhosted.org/web2py_utils/test_runner.html).